# How to convert Array of Indexed Associative Array to Comma Separated Associative Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I have an indexed Associative Array like

```
[
0:{abc: 123, xyz: 456, foo: null, bar: 0}
1:{abc: 235, xyz: 556, foo: null, bar: 0}
]
```

now how to convert it to comma separated form

```
[{abc: 123, xyz: 456, foo: null, bar: 0},{abc: 235, xyz: 556, foo: null, bar: 0}
    ]
```

Comment: please add valid data, as it looks, the first should be an object, not an array with keys.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: probably your array is on a form you rcan already use what you try to achive?

Comment: Sorry Bros It is my second Question I think, I will read all the help and post better Questions Next Time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an array as target object.

```js
var data = { 0: { abc: 123, xyz: 456, foo: null, bar: 0 }, 1: { abc: 235, xyz: 556, foo: null, bar: 0 } },
    array = Object.assign([], data);

console.log(array);
```

Or just [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) if the index does not matter.

```js
var data = { 0: { abc: 123, xyz: 456, foo: null, bar: 0 }, 1: { abc: 235, xyz: 556, foo: null, bar: 0 } },
    array = Object.values(data);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first variable is an object instead of array, you can do:

```
object = Object.keys(object).map(key => object[key]);
```