# How to unify different array data into 1 data arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a data array is as below:

```
array = [
 0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c'
]
```

I want to make the data array is as below

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Please help I really need this :')
thank you...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Array of Indexed Associative Array to Comma Separated Associative Array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090988/how-to-convert-array-of-indexed-associative-array-to-comma-separated-associative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an object not array

```
array = {
 0: 'a',
 1: 'b',
 2: 'c'
}
```

you can use for in to get array from object

```js
var array = {
    "item-0": 'a',
    "item-1": 'b',
    "item-2": 'c'
}

var t = [];
for (const key in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        t.push(array[key]);

    }
}

console.log(t)
```

is as array

Comment: If it's an object, you can just use the built in `Object.values(array)`. No need for the loop.

Comment: yeah it is better way